# Tree not builiding

Tags: c++, tree

I was trying to build my own binary search tree. However , my tree is not getting built. Please see code below and help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class Binarytree 
{  
private:
    struct node
    { 
      int data;
      node *left;
      node *right;
    };
    node  *root;


public:
    Binarytree();
    void insertdata(node*,int);
    void deletedata();
    void printdata(node*);
    void userprint(char);
    void getdata(int);

};

Binarytree::Binarytree()
{
    root=NULL;
    cout<<"Setting root as NULL"<<endl;
}

void Binarytree::insertdata(node* temp3,int temp)
{   cout << "in insert data"<<endl;

    node Dummy=node();
    Dummy.data=temp;
    Dummy.left=NULL;
    Dummy.right=NULL;


    cout << "Data To be inserted is  "<<temp <<endl;

    if  (temp3 == NULL)
      {  cout<<"Found NULL ROOT"<<endl; 
          temp3=&Dummy;
          cout << "Entered a Data in tree"<<endl;
          cout<<"Data in root"<<root->data<<endl;
    }


    else if (temp3->data > temp)
    { cout<<"Making a Left Recursive Call"<<endl;
     insertdata(temp3->left,temp);
    }

    else 
    { cout<<"Making a right  Recursive Call"<<endl;
        insertdata(temp3->right,temp);
    }



  }

void Binarytree::getdata(int check)
{   cout <<"in getdata"<<endl;

    cout << "before insertdata"<<endl;

    insertdata(root,check);

}

void Binarytree::printdata(node* printrt)
{
    if (printrt ==NULL)
         cout << "Nothing to print";
    else
        { cout << printrt->data << endl;
          printdata(printrt->left);
          printdata(printrt->right);
                   }

}

void Binarytree::userprint(char in)
{   node* data;
    data=root;
    if (in == 'Y' || in == 'y')
      printdata(data);
}

void main()
{    Binarytree element=Binarytree();
     int userdata,i=0;
     bool check = true;


     while(check)
    { cout <<"Please Enter your Data"<<endl;
     cin >> userdata;
     element.getdata(userdata);
     cout<<"FUnction returned to main"<<endl;
     i++;
     if(i==5)
         check=false;

     }
     element.userprint('Y');

}
```

The very first value is not getting inserted in root pointer. I know there are lots of code available for doing this but if i don't code it my own I feel my learning will be limited.
So please help in figuring error in this code.

Comment: `temp3=&Dummy;` doesn't sound right saving a pointer to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having really tried to compile and there might be other problems... but

change

```
void Binarytree::insertdata(node* temp3,int temp)
```

to

```
void Binarytree::insertdata(node* &temp3,int temp)
```

so that the node created inside insertdata really modifies the outside pointer.

and change

```
node Dummy=node();
Dummy.data=temp;
Dummy.left=NULL;
Dummy.right=NULL;
```

to

```
node *Dummy=new node();
Dummy->data=temp;
Dummy->left=NULL;
Dummy->right=NULL;
```

As I said there might be other problems... you should worry about deleting nodes and all that...

Alternative you could create nodes outside of insertdata() and keep the same signature.

Anyway, good luck

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you explain me the difference . Like why we used 1)node* &temp3 in place of node* temp3 and 2) why we had to create a pointer to form new node from user input. why the normal node didn't work.

Comment: @user3440629 about 1)... with temp3 * you are passing by value a parameter which is of type pointer. passing by value means that inside de method you have a copy of the parameter with(initially) the same value.... if yoy modify this copy, the change is not represented outside. Using temp3* &  means a parameter passed by reference, and the modifications  inside the method affects outside the method, because it is not a copy, it is a reference to the same value

Comment: @user3440629 about 2)... in your code you were using a local variable allocated on the stack and that it will go away when you go out of the scope. Must use new to allocate from the heap.... but you must take care of deleting this memory yourself

Answer (score 0):

The root cause (if you'll pardon the pun) is the way you're adding things to the root of the tree.  Your code creates a *temporary* variable called `Dummy` on the stack and then takes its address.  That's the first mistake because that temporary variable gets destroyed when the function ends.

The second problem is that in order to change the value of a pointer that you pass to a function, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer.  In other words, your member function that was `insertdata(node *, int)` must become `insertdata(node **, int)`if you want to actually change the passed pointer rather than just a local copy as your original code had done.

To illustrate that fact, try this code.

```
#include <iostream>

int Y = 99;

void makeitsix(int n) {
    n = 6;
}

void pointToY(int *ptr) {
    ptr = &Y;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *p = &x;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", *p = " << *p << std::endl;
    makeitsix(x);
    pointToY(p);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", *p = " << *p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When `makeitsix()` gets called, it's only the local copy of `n` that is altered, and not the value of 5 that was originally passed in.  Similarly, `ptr` in the `pointToY()` function is only altering a local copy of `ptr` and not `p` that was used to call the function from within `main()`.  If it were not so, an invocation such as `makeitsix(3)` would lead to some *very* strange effects!

I took the liberty of changing things somewhat in your code to make it a little cleaner, including

1. giving the `node` structure its own constructor
2. creating an extractor for the Binarytree
3. removing the various diagnostic printout statements (for brevity)
4. making the tree printout look more like a tree with the root to the left and the branches extending rightward
5. made some member functions private

and a few other minor things.  The complete working code is below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Binarytree 
{  
private:
    struct node
    { 
      node(int d=0) : data(d), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
      int data;
      node *left;
      node *right;
    };
    node  *root;
    void insertdata(node**,int);
    std::ostream& printdata(std::ostream &out, node*, int depth=0);

public:
    Binarytree() : root(NULL) {};
    std::ostream &printTo(std::ostream &out);
    void insert(int);
};

void Binarytree::insertdata(node** temp3,int temp)
{   
    node *Dummy=new node(temp);

    if  (*temp3 == NULL) {  
        *temp3=Dummy;
    } else if ((*temp3)->data > temp) { 
        insertdata(&((*temp3)->left),temp);
    } else { 
        insertdata(&((*temp3)->right),temp);
    }
}

void Binarytree::insert(int check)
{   
    insertdata(&root,check);
}

std::ostream &Binarytree::printdata(std::ostream &out, node* printrt, int depth)
{
    if (printrt != NULL)
    { 
        printdata(out, printrt->left, depth+1);
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) 
            out << '\t';
        out << printrt->data << std::endl;
        printdata(out, printrt->right, depth+1);
    }
    return out;
}

std::ostream &Binarytree::printTo(std::ostream &out)
{   
      return printdata(out, root);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Binarytree &b)
{
    return b.printTo(out);
}

int main()
{    
    Binarytree element;
    int userdata,i=0;
    bool check = true;

    while(check)
    { 
        std::cout << "Please Enter your Data" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userdata;
        element.insert(userdata);
        i++;
        if(i==5)
            check=false;

    }
    std::cout << "Tree:\n" << element << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edward. Can you explain me this pointer to pointer thing ? I didn't get that part.

Comment: I've updated to answer to try to better explain that point.  Let me know if it's still not clear.